# Laravel 5.2 multiple file_get_contents() not working on prod

Tags: php, apache, laravel, amazon-s3

I have a form which accepts multiple images (logo, cover, thumbnail) in different sections of the form. I'm trying to upload these to Amazon s3. In my controller:

```
public function store(Request $request){

  Storage::disk('s3')->put(
    $request->user()->id.'/thumbnail.png',
    file_get_contents($request->file('thumbnail')),
    'public'
  );
  Storage::disk('s3')->put(
    $request->user()->id.'/cover.png',
    file_get_contents($request->file('cover')),
    'public'
  );
  Storage::disk('s3')->put(
    $request->user()->id.'/logo.png',
    file_get_contents($request->file('logo')),
    'public'
  );

}
```

I'm able to upload and fetch URL of this uploaded image on localhost but i get **"file_get_contents: filename cannot be empty error"** on production which is an Amazon linux instance with LAMP. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You should alwyas check if file was uploaded:

```
if ($request->hasFile('thumbnail'))
   Storage::disk('s3')->put(
        $request->user()->id.'/thumbnail.png',
        file_get_contents($request->file('thumbnail')),
        'public'
   );
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/requests#files

Comment: So i was uploading a large image file for cover ( Around 7mb), so i presume the upload was not valid which eventually did not upload the 'logo'. Any thought around the why the fileupload failed for a large file? My code worked for a small image size otherwise.

Comment: You will likely find an answer [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/file-validation-failing-on-larger-files?page=1)